# Does the notion of "percentages" extend to countably infinite and uncountably infinite sets?

Tags: probability-theory, percentages

In the case of finite sets, e.g. $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, if some asked me, *"What percentage of the numbers are even in $A$?"*, I would respond with $50 \%$. If asked for a proof, I'd demonstrate that two of the four elements in the set are even.

Now, consider the set $B=\mathbb N$, which is countably infinite. If someone asked me, *"What percentage of the numbers are even in $B$?"*, intuitively, I would think the answer is $50 \%$. However, I'm not sure how I would go about proving this.

Finally, consider the set $C = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, which is uncountably infinite. If someone asked me, *"What percentage of numbers are greater than $0$ in $C$?"*, I would think the answer is $50 \%$. Once again, I'm unsure of how I could demonstrate this must be true.

So as the title of this post states, does the notion of "percentages" extend to countably infinite and uncountably infinite sets?

Comment: The short version of the answer is: not without some additional "structure." The relevant term to search for is **measure** (measure theory, Lebesgue measure, probability measure, ...) and there are a number of questions on this site about it. The rough idea is that in general a set will admit many differently-behaving measures, and we can't talk about probabilities/percentages/etc. without specifying a particular measure. This is even true for finite sets in a way except that every finite set carries exactly one measure giving each singleton subset the same measure (the **counting measure**).

Comment: I've made this a comment instead of an answer since I'm highly confident that this is a duplicate question (not that that's independently a bad thing, of course).

Comment: @NoahSchweber thank you. Let me know if it is and I'll happily delete it - nothing popped up when I did an initial search...I'm guessing if I had used the word "measure", something *would* have matched. The motivation for this question is trying to understand the PMF for a geometric random variable:  $\text{Pr}(X=k)=(1-p)^k\cdot p$. It seems here that the intuition behind this function definition is that "percentages" play nicely with uncountably infinite sets.

Comment: @NoahSchweber i.e. if $X$ is reporting the number of flips required before I get a **H**ead on my coin flip, and $p=0.50$, then $\text{Pr}(X=1)$ is $0.50$...which to me seems like its saying "$50\%$ of all my infinite sequences of coin flips have heads on the first trial."

Comment: Hmm... I wrote an answer, but of course if there's a duplicate then probably the question will be closed.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes, thank you! Any input on my commentary about the geometric random variable intuition?

Comment: S.Cramer, we would instead say (something like) "According to the Lebesgue measure on the set $2^\mathbb{N}$ of all infinite binary sequences, the set $\{f: f(0)=0\}\subseteq 2^\mathbb{N}$ (thinking of $0$ as "Heads") has measure $1\over 2$." Percentages, per se, aren't talked about. (And maybe this isn't a duplicate after all @LeeMosher, it was just a hunch on my part.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber perfect. Thank you, sir. Cheers~

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density - this might be down your alley. It formalizes the notion of "half of all integers are even"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, although the word "percentage" is not used in those cases, instead the word used is "probability" (if you are doing statistics) or "measure" (if you are doing mathematics).

For a countable set like $\mathbb N$ you need to assign a probability $p_n \in [0,1]$ to each $n \in \mathbb N$, subject to the rule that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} p_n = 1$ (which is therefore an convergent infinite series); that rule is the analogue in probability theory of the rule that $100\%$ means "everything". Examples of this include the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) which is used to model the probability that $n$ people will walk through that door in the next minute.

For an uncountable set like $\mathbb R$ you can generally use integral calculus to define probabilities: instead of convergent infinite series on uses convergent improper integrals. Examples include [Gaussian distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), also known as "normal distributions", which are used to model and estimate the proportion of heads to expect when you flip a zillion coins.